# xls to text converter

Tags: linux, excel, unix, converters, xls

Anyone know of a free xls to text converter that can be run from the unix command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also the package [catdoc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/intrepid/catdoc) (Ubuntu link) that includes a xls2csv utility.

Comment: There's also a cygwin package for it. Just what I needed.

Comment: `$ brew install catdoc` for any Mac/homebrew users.

Comment: `catdoc` has been added to the Homebrew boneyard: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-boneyard/commit/8fe3f1cce16cfa910005782baae27b85f6069cd9

Comment: `catdoc` is no longer accessible from the boneyard.  Can still use Homebrew with [this ruby script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/294259) and then `brew install --build-from-source catdoc.rb`

Comment: The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/catdoc) says that catdoc reads **MS-Word files**. Not xls.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search of `apt-cache` turned up the [Ubuntu package python-excelerator](http://packages.ubuntu.com/intrepid/python-excelerator) for [excelerator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyExcelerator/0.6.0a), which includes `py_xls2html`, `py_xls2csv` and `py_xls2txt` utlities. Will this work for you?

Comment: It is not present in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

Your question reminded me of [anti-word](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/). I looked up and found [anti-excel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/antiexcel/). I have never used it, so I can't vouch for how well it work or whether it makes achievable the task you have at hand. Also, I remember using a utility called 'sc' on linux to created spreadsheets on the console---though, I do not know whether it is capable of interpreting XLS files.

Answer (score 1):

I think gnumeric is better to convert document to csv http://xmodulo.com/2012/06/how-to-convert-xlsx-files-to-xls-or-csv.html